Getting Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Provided identity doesn't belong to the resource' in Azure Communication Services
I am getting
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Provided identity doesn't belong to the resource.*
*Status: 401 (Unauthorized)
ErrorCode: IdentityNotOwned*.**

I am calling the Azure Comm Services from Azure Functions where I have APIs created for chat functions, This issue happened after the UAT environment was deleted and re-deployed via ARM Template, we have Azure Comm Services for chat functionality, and the error occurs when calling the below line -
communicationIdentityClient.GetTokenAsync(new CommunicationUserIdentifier(userDetails.AcsUserId), scopes: new[] { CommunicationTokenScope.Chat });


Are you using managed identitiy for auth?
